# Is it correct to say: "In hindsight everyone is an expert"

Tags: phrase-usage

I was wondering if this is correct to express everyone is an expert only after a particular situation happens and they complaint about it after the fact.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to find out if it is grammatically correct to say: " In hindsight everyone is an expert."

Answer (score 1):

Clever adage you've got there; bonus points if you figured it out yourself.  I interpret this phrase sarcastically—not to mean that people who complain after something happens are actually experts through the wisdom of experience, but rather that people tend to think they predicted the future when they really didn't.  People tend to remember fulfilled expectations better than unfulfilled ones, so, indeed, "in hindsight, everyone [thinks they are] an expert."

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. It is my first one here. Most definitely there is a sarcastic intention behind it. I read somewhere after I posted this question a phrase for hindsight that I found equally sarcastic but I guess a bit more formal: "Everyone's an expert with the virtue of  hindsight."